# SPRING BOOT - How to access classes from Super POM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, pom.xml

I have created a parent project so I can have all the common dependencies, DTOs, services, helpers, etc. that I will use in all my common projects.

**This parent project is imported as POM:**

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.whitehawk</groupId>
<artifactId>hawk-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>hawk-parent</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>Parent configuration for microservices</description>
```

**In the other projects I have:**

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.whitehawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawk-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<artifactId>customers</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>customers</name>
<description>Customers microservice</description>
```

The dependencies have been imported correctly, but I am not able to access for example my `Role` enum even if it has public access modifier.

```
public enum Role {
    CUSTOMER,
    ADMIN,
    SUPERADMIN
}
```

**Or my `@UserRole` annotation:**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface UserRole {
    Role[] value();
}
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Cheers!

**Update**:

Following suggestions, I added a new module: hawk-core

Its POM looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.whitehawk</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>hawk-core</artifactId>
    <name>hawk-core</name>
    <description>Core libraries for microservices</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

And included this in the parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.whitehawk</groupId>
<artifactId>hawk-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>hawk-parent</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>Parent configuration for microservices</description>

<modules>
    <module>hawk-core</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: so you packed parent project into jar file and added that in class path libraries?

Comment: Define shared classes not in a parent project but rather another child project that you define as a regular dependency.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum

So you mean that I have something like:
hawk-parent POM
 - utilities POM

<modules>
   <utilities>
</modules>

What different that it makes?

Comment: Your parent can be a pom not  jar with classes. Even if it could you would need to declare it as a dependency and not just a parent. Your project will only inherit dependencies, build info etc. from the parent NOT classes defined in there unless it is defined as dependency as well.

Comment: Hello @M.Deinum I updated the post with the new structure, but I still did not make this work. I am not able to build it because missing main classes. Should I really include them? It does not have so much sense to me. Cheers!

Comment: The core project needs to be a dependency of the other projects that require those classes. Next to that that probably shouldn't be a spring boot project as you don't want to run it with Spring Boot (you want the dependencies not the packaging!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is misunderstanding here for 2 things:

1- packaging: this field is used as POM if you are not having classes to be package in jar/war file, this used for example for parent project which is not used as dependancies or packaged to be deployed.

2- dependancies: this decencies is used for adding lib packages you required for your project from sample you have here you are not including this, so the classes will not be seen in your project

suggest to have a parent project that not have any classes and have 2 modules one is your core classes to be jar as lib, and second one as spring boot you may refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent and have the first module as dependency in your second module to be like:

```
parent
 |
 |-core
    |-pomt.xml
 |-app
    |-pomt.xml
 |-pom.xml
```

Comment: Hello, I updated the post with the changes I did following your advice.
The problem is that I am not able now to build this as I am getting "Unable to find main class". Do I really need to add main clases to these packages? Does not make so much sense to me.
Cheers!

Comment: First you are using 2 different parents, Ijust shared Link to not use spring boot as parent, second in spring boot project have to have class with @SpringBoot

Comment: Here is link for main class you have to have https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-code

Comment: Hello, I was finally able to do it. Thanks for your help. I just need to see why I broke the Spring Boot plugin ("mvn spring-boot:run"), as I am importing it in my "children" but now the aplication is not starting, just building. I will keep looking at it. Cheers

Comment: Okay, fixed! I just forgot to remove the plugin from the parent, so for some reason is not being overrided in the children. I just removed from parent, as I will never need it there, and now is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Correct parent will be only container for projects